# ZeroMQ: Can someone please explain how HWM works?

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I'm experimenting with ZeroMQ, I have a **`PUSH`** application that sends ~370,000 messages, each of 10Kb in size.

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket  = context.socket( zmq.PUSH )
socket.bind( "tcp://127.0.0.1:5557" )

no_msgs =      0
i       = 370000

fd  = open( "input_text_files/file1.txt", 'r' )
msg = fd.read()

while i >  0:
    print "Sending data of size" , len( msg )
    rc       = socket.send( msg )
    no_msgs += 1
    if rc == None:
        print True
    if rc == -1:
        print "ERROR!!"

    i = i-1
```

The **`PULL`** application just received the messages in a loop:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket  = context.socket( zmq.PULL )
socket.connect( "tcp://127.0.0.1:5557" )

no_msgs = 1
i       = 1

while True:
    msg      = socket.recv()
    no_msgs += 1
    print "Received msg", i
    print "Received %s" %( len( msg ) )
    i = i + 1
```

With this setting, there are messages lost i.e., the `PULL` socket did not receive all 370,000 messages. I added `socket.hwm = 10` on the `PUSH` socket and all 370,000 messages were received. Can someone explain to me how this works?

Comment: on which side did you add the socket.hwm , pull or push?

Comment: @somdoron  On the PUSH side

Answer (score 2):

### Well, HighWaterMarks are a set of delicate settings:

these work "down under the hood" of the ZeroMQ **`.Context()`** instance

May be, start reading a bit about ZeroMQ internals, next try to distinguish between non-blocking v/s blocking mode of operations.

> `ZMQ_RCVBUF: Set kernel receive buffer size           | default -1 == O/S def'd`
>   `ZMQ_RCVHWM: Set high water mark for inbound messages | default 1000`
>   `ZMQ_SNDBUF: Set kernel transmit buffer size          | default -1 == O/S def'd`
>   `ZMQ_SNDHWM: Set high water mark for outbound messages| default 1000`
>
> The `ZMQ_SNDHWM` option shall set the high water mark for outbound messages on the specified socket. The high water mark is a hard limit on the maximum number of outstanding messages ØMQ shall queue in memory for any single peer that the specified socket is communicating with. A value of zero means no limit.
>
> If this limit has been reached the socket shall enter an exceptional state and depending on the socket type, ØMQ shall take appropriate action such as **blocking** or **dropping** sent messages. Refer to the individual socket descriptions in [`zmq_socket(3)`](http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq_socket) for details on the exact action taken for each socket type.
>
> ØMQ **does not guarantee** that the socket will accept as many as `ZMQ_SNDHWM` messages, and the actual limit may be as much as 60-70% lower depending on the flow of messages on the socket.

### ZMQ_PUSH:

> A socket of type `ZMQ_PUSH` is used by a pipeline node to send messages to downstream pipeline nodes. Messages are round-robined to all connected downstream nodes. The `zmq_recv()` function is not implemented for this socket type.
>
> When a `ZMQ_PUSH` socket enters the mute state **due to having reached the high water mark** for all downstream nodes, **or if there are no downstream nodes** at all, then any `zmq_send(3)` **operations on the socket shall block** until the mute state ends or at least one downstream node becomes available for sending; messages are not discarded.

### ZMQ_RECVHWM:  <sup>... the `PULL` side settings</sup>

> The **`ZMQ_RCVHWM`** option shall set the high water mark for inbound messages on the specified socket. The **high water mark is a hard limit on the maximum number of outstanding messages ØMQ shall queue in memory** for any single peer that the specified socket is communicating with. A value of zero means no limit.
>   If this limit has been reached the socket shall enter an exceptional state and depending on the socket type, ØMQ shall take appropriate action such as blocking or **dropping** sent messages. Refer to the individual socket descriptions in `zmq_socket(3)` for details on the exact action taken for each socket type.